# Can I stay in other Schengen countries on a national type D visa for more than 90 days?

Tags: international-travel, italy, poland, long-stay-visas, 90-180-visa-rules

I have a Polish national type D visa, and would like to stay in Italy for more than 90  days in 180 day period. 
I was actually wondering if its possible considering there are not border checks betwen Schengen countries?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't do this. The [Polish Ministry of Foreign Affairs](https://www.gov.pl/web/diplomacy/visas) says:

> A D-type national visa permits to enter the territory of the Republic
>   of Poland and to stay continuously or for several successive times in
>   this territory for a total duration of more than 90 days during the
>   period of validity of the visa, but not longer than one year.
>
> A D-type national visa also permits to travel in the territory of
>   other Schengen Area Member States for up to 90 days during a 180-day
>   period, during the validity period of the visa.

In short, you can stay in Poland for the duration of the visa. Elsewhere in the Schengen area the 90/180 rule applies.

The absence of border controls may mean it is possible, but member states can and do perform checks at borders and elsewhere on an ad hoc basis. Being caught breaching the terms of your visa will make life difficult, at best.

Comment: "member states can and do perform checks at borders and elsewhere on an ad hoc basis": such a check will not uncover the violation, however, since the passport contains no record of internal travels.  The only way someone is going to get in trouble for this is if they get in trouble for something else and the police investigate their whereabouts.